# What is ng-reflect-router-link? Why is not showing up for a button in inspect element section

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routerlink

As far as I understand ng-reflect-router-link is used for debugging. And tells which link has the element being routed to. But ng-reflect-router-link is not showing up for me for a button.

I created two button in two different modules, keeping the whole process similar. Unfortunately, one button is working and other is not. And the html elements upon inspection is as follows:

Button that works:

```html
<button _ngcontent-qun-c23="" class="btn btn-success" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/tags/add">Add Tag</button>
```

Button that does not work:

```html
<button _ngcontent-rvm-c25="" routerlink="['/languages/add']" class="btn btn-success">Add language</button>
```

What am I missing here? Any hints on how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it was a very small mistake: I had not imported the **language** module in `app.module.ts`. So even though, I have made all imports in the `language.module.ts`, only HTML data will be shown and the Angular elements will not work.